# AltGr key combinations through Qtnx 

Tags: remote, keyboard-layout, nx

I started using Qtnx, and it works great.
I have a problem accessing some keyboard characters though. I am using a french keyboard (azerty-like), and every character is mapped correctly with qtnx, except for some <kbd>AltGr</kbd> keys, which are needed for characters such as `` #{[|`\^@]} ``, which are in the top row (along with all the digits). I need to be able to write these characters!

Both computers (the one running Qtnx, and the one being remotely accessed) use Ubuntu 10.04. Apart from switching to a US keyboard layout, is there another solution?

Comment: I think this is a bug on qtnx, but is there a work around ? for example, maybe I could write a script so that when I use a particular key, I get the character I'm supposed to ? I wouldn't know how to do that though, and I'm really out of ideas, so please help me. I do need these special characters for my usual work.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is a problem with locales definition and X11 (in case Qtnx uses directly some old low level X11 keyboard reading).

To test it, launch Qtnx with LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
if the AltGr works, then it is a wrong locale configuration, and can be fixed.

First, type the "locales" command and see what exactly is the locale string used; then check in the locale.dir and compose.dir (they should be under /usr/share/X11/locale/ or a similar path; use locate to find them) that you have lines for that exact string.

if not, you can edit those files; copy the lines (there are two, one with colon, one without colon) for "en_US.UTF-8" and change them to match your locale string.
Or, if a similar locale exists already, but with a different spelling (a common problem is ".UTF-8" vs ".utf8", you can edit the locale.alias file at the same directory to add an alias; eg, if "locale" reports you use "fr_FR.utf8", but in the locale.dir there is only "fr_FR.UTF-8", you can put in the locale.alias file those two lines (note one has a colon):

```
fr_FR.utf8    fr_FR.UTF-8
fr_FR.utf8:   fr_FR.UTF-8
```